# You're three for three

Tags: phrase-meaning

Here is a dialogue from Dilbert:

> **Pointy-Haired Boss:**  Now let's hear what Dilbert did this week.
>
> **Dilbert:**  I unnecessarily duplicated Ted's work because you forgot you asked both of us to do the same task.
>
> **Pointy-Haired Boss:**  And how about Alice?.
>
> **Alice:**  You're three for three.

What does three for three mean here, or how can I parse it? She did the same task also?

I have not managed to find a definition for `three for three`, but apparently `two for two` comes from baseball and means "successful at both attempts".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(number) for (number) simply means "you were successful (number) attempts out of (number) attempts"

So you could be "seven for nine" or any other combination, athough it is rarely used that way outside of sports like baseball.

In this case Dilbert basically said "Ted and I were asked the same thing so we did the thing twice" and Alice said "actually all three of us were asked the same thing and all three did the thing"

Comment: So she is saying something like "out of your three attempts to get the task done, you succeeded all three times"?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: As a native British English speaker, I would note that I consider "(number) for (number)" to be an American English phrase.

Comment: @AndyT Sounds like cricket terminology to me.

Comment: In cricket "X for Y" means X runs for Y wickets, which doesn't mean the same thing (even figuratively).

Comment: @Wilson Note that in this context it is undesirable for the employees to have completed the work, so the three "successes" here are not actually a good outcome. Alice is being sarcastic.

Comment: In cricket a score of "3 for 3" would mean one team (i.e. PHB) has made a disastrous start - which figuratively makes sense, even if it's not what Scott Adams had in mind when he wrote the words.

Comment: As Tashus said. It's more like "you've succeeded at being a terrible manager, three times". (Although, due to [the fencepost problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error), it's really more like two times!)

Comment: The "You're X for Y" terminology originated in baseball (where X is number of hits and Y is plate appearances) and quickly spread to other American sports such as basketball and football (X is made baskets, field goals, extra point kicks, completed passes; y is attempts thereof).